# Joining multiple tables to achieve result set in a specific style

Tags: sql, outer-join, full-outer-join

I have 3 tables in the same database, with couple of columns as common and rest non-matching columns as well. I need to show them together in such a fashion that the user should be able to distinguish between the source tables (Refer below diagrams). I want to know if I can achieve this in database itself, before passing its result on to my report UI or code behind?

I have tried achieving this using OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN.
See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tgzm.jpg)

Also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Zmi.jpg)

Comment: Assuming your code is in the image links; FYI, folks at work (like myself) may not be able to view these images. I'd recommend posting your code directly in the question so a wider range of people can assist you.

Comment: Could you not do a inner join based on common columns between 3 tables?